# How to add a constraints in OptaPlanner for vehicle routing

Tags: optaplanner

I am working on vehicle routing problem where by I have to implement a constraint that ensures specific location/s shouldn't be the 1st or last location to be traversed.
Any idea how can this be addressed ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

The easy way:

```
if (Customer.getPreviousStandstill instanceOf Vehicle) // first visit

if (Customer.getNextCustomer == null) // last visit
```

The hard way (in case you need to single out the 37th visit etc):

In the planning entity `Customer`, add a shadow variable `visitNumber`, in `Vehicle`, add a shadow variable `visitNumberTotal`. Then use `VariableListeners` to keep those in sync.

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate this, will try out this solution.